# How to fix image showing as symbols in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5

I'm using this package [simple-qrcode](https://www.simplesoftware.io/simple-qrcode/) to generate a qr code .
so Im generating it when a user clicks a button in a vue component.

When i generate the qrcode which works fine but all i get is weird symbols that is not a qrcode.

A [Screen Shot](http://prntscr.com/p9prex)

I'm returning the `QrCode` as a response :

```
return response($Qrcode)->header('Content-type','image/png');
```

if i access the url in the browser i can see the qrcode image just fine :\ .

how im showing the code in vue component :

```
showQrcode() {

    axios.get(`/api/qrcode/${this.postTitle}/${this.id}`)
        .then(res => {
            this.qrCode = res.data;

        })
}
```

the result :

[screen shot 2](http://prntscr.com/p9pweh)

the data is just a bunch of werid symbols .

Any idea how i can solve this?

I tried to `return json($qrcode)` but it's returning an empty page.

Comment: Could you just set the url to the `src` attribute of an `<img src="">`? Ajax is usually used for textual data, but not for binary data (in this case an image). You could also e.g.  encode your image as base64 and transmit it like that, then it is easily transmittable via Ajax.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. You're returning your image as raw binary data. Please have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51411544/display-raw-image-content-type-in-vue-js)

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 thanks for the advice .. i did encode the image `response(base64_encode($code))` and in my vue component ```<img :src="`data:image/png;base64,${qrCode}`" />``` its working like a charm

Comment: Great! Keep in mind that base64 has a larger file size than raw binary data. So, your losing a bit of performance (transmitted data amount is larger) when using base64 over binary data. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11402374/3233827

Comment: good to know ! thank you so much